# Can't add any .htaccess entrys with yourls installed

Tags: php, .htaccess, yourls

I have a website, tini.link, and I want to speed it up a bit. I know what to add to the .htaccess file, BUT, every time I try to add any entry to the file, I get a 500 internal server error. Is there any way around this?
Flynn

Comment: You must have to start rewrite_module from the apache server,

go to httpd.conf file and uncomment the following line.

'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so'